# What is wrong with my Opera installing ? - Public key not available - 16.04

Tags: apt, gnupg, opera

I don't really know what to try.

From the error message it looks like the Opera source is simply missing a signature and to me that means I should not try to use the file because I need to trust Opera when I use it.

If I can do something to refresh or fix the information on my computer about the public key it could solve the problem I think.

```
sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [102 kB]                   
Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                       
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [102 kB]                                
Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                             
Get:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [102 kB]                  
Get:7 https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable stable InRelease [2,592 B]                          
Err:7 https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable stable InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY D615560BA5C7FF72
Fetched 309 kB in 1s (276 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
1 package can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see it.
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY D615560BA5C7FF72
W: Failed to fetch https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable/dists/stable/InRelease  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY D615560BA5C7FF72
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To install a Ubuntu compatible version of Opera... first add the missing GPG key... then install Opera...

In `terminal`...

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/y-ppa-manager # add repository
sudo apt-get update                                   # update software database
sudo apt-get install y-ppa-manager                    # install y-ppa-manager
y-ppa-manager                                         # start y-ppa-manager
    click on the "Advanced" icon
    select "Try to import all missing GPG keys" and click OK
sudo apt-get update                                   # update software database
sudo apt-get install opera                            # install opera
```

Comment: It worked to use <code>sudo apt-get install opera</code>. Also, then it wanted to do an update within the browser, and the update worked also.

Comment: @HillofBeans Great news! Thanks for the update.